# How to change date format in Thunderbird

Tags: linux, date, thunderbird

The date format in the date column (inbox folder) is as follow: dd-mm-yy hh:mm. The problem is that when displaying emails from days or months represented by a single digit it messes up the alignment of the dates and it's driving me crazy

Is there a way to turn this

```
dd-mm-yy hh:mm
22/12/19 17:57
1/1/19 2:34     <--
```

into this?

```
dd-mm-yy hh:mm
22/12/19 17:57
01/01/19 02:34  <--
```

PS: I'am using Pop_OS 19.10

EDIT: I am using spanish(Spain) locale

Comment: How annoying! I don't have this problem. I am using Fedora Linux. In Thunderbird, Preferences -> Advanced -> General, I have a heading "Date and Time formatting", which shows that my locale is "English (United Kingdom)".  Could you edit your question to say what locale you are using?  Also I see four-digit years in Thunderbird date column... even though, if I look in Gnome Settings -> Region and Language -> Formats, the date example is shown with two digit years.

Comment: @sourcejedi I've updated the question adding the locale info.

Comment: thanks! If I use Gnome Settings to switch to that (España (Español)) & log out and back in again, then I have the exact same problem. I don't know why. If possible I suggest writing a bug report for Thunderbird, including this information.

Comment: @sourcejedi Thank you. I'll do that.